# why sequelize try to select an extra column when i do a query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am creating a database for a store, the products from the store have a category and the categories have several subcategories.
The problem is when I try to establish a OneToMany relationship between categories and subcategories (a category has several subcategories and a subcategory has one category).

This is the category model:

```js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class category extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      category.belongsTo(models.product);
      category.hasMany(models.subcategory);
    }
  }
  category.init(
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      productId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "category",
    }
  );
  return category;
};
```

And this is the subcategory model:

```js
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class subcategory extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      subcategory.hasOne(models.category);
    }
  }
  subcategory.init(
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      categoryId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "subcategory",
    }
  );
  return subcategory;
};
```

I have also created the endpoints to be able to list all the categories:

```js
const category = require("../models").category;
module.exports = {
  list(_, res) {
    return category
      .findAll({})
      .then((category) => {
        res.status(200).send(category);
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};
```

I have also created the routes to test it, the problem I have is that when I make a request to that endpoint, I get the following error:

```
{
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "parent": {
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'subcategoryId' in 'field list'",
    "sql": "SELECT `id`, `name`, `productId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `subcategoryId` FROM `categories` AS `category`;"
  },
  "original": {
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'subcategoryId' in 'field list'",
    "sql": "SELECT `id`, `name`, `productId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `subcategoryId` FROM `categories` AS `category`;"
  },
  "sql": "SELECT `id`, `name`, `productId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `subcategoryId` FROM `categories` AS `category`;"
}
```

As you can see, the error is that it tries to select a column (subcategoryId) that does not exist and the truth is that I do not know why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `subcategory` depends on `category` then you need to use `belongsTo` from the `subcategory` side instead of `hasOne`:

```js
subcategory.belongsTo(models.category);
```

`hasOne` is used to indicate a link from the other side of `belongsTo` and also means 1-to-1 link,

Comment: I have belongsToMany() from both ends through another table, still getting this issue

Comment: Then please ask one more question with the link to this one for clarification

Comment: @Anatoly did you fix your issue? I have NO relationships defined and I still get an extra column selected

Comment: Did you replace `subcategory.hasOne(models.category)` with `subcategory.belongsTo(models.category)`?